# How to tell that a c++ application has disk I/O bottleneck?

Tags: c++, indexing, full-text-search, disk, solid-state-drive

I'm working on a "search" project. The main idea is how to build a index to respond to the search request as fast as possible. The input is a query, such as "termi termj", ouput is docs where both termi and termj appear.

the index file looks like this:(each line is called a postlist, which is sorted array of unsigned int and can be compressed with good compression ratio)

`term1:doc1, doc5, doc8, doc10
term2:doc10, doc51, doc111, doc10000
...
termN:doc2, doc4, doc10`

3 main time resuming procedure is

1. seek termi and termj's postlist in file (random disk read)
2. decode the postlists (cpu)
3. calculate the intersection of 2 postlists (cpu)

My question is, How can I know that the application can't be more efficient, it has a disk I/O bottleneck? How can I measure if my computer has used his disk 100 percent? Are there any tools on linux to help? Is there any tools can measure disk I/O perfectly like [google cpu profiler](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/cpu_profiler.html) can measure cpu?

My develop env is Ubuntu 14.04.

```
CPU: 8 cores 2.6GHz
disk: SSD
benchmark now is about 2000 queries/second, but I don't know how to improve it.
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: I've tried iostat, the information is useful but I don't know if the disk has reach its ceiling

Comment: How big is the index?

Comment: total 28 million documents, 11 million terms, the index file size is about 10GB after each postlist been compressed by PFor compression algorithm(compression ratio is about 25% of its original size).

Comment: 10GB can fit in RAM and you don't need any disk I/O.

Comment: Yes, but it is only an experiment, which contains part of the data, the postlists file size will reach 60G or more in the future.

Comment: 60GB can fit in RAM if you buy more RAM. I bring it up since you say speed is the most important thing, and it doesn't matter how fast the disk is if you don't need it. You can get servers with several terabytes of RAM (at least 6000GB)  but I'm sure they aren't cheap.

Comment: of course I don't know the answer to your actual question, I just thought that was something worth bringing up if speed is really really important